# Repeat vector over itself

Tags: r

Say I have a vector:

```
tt <- c("test", "this" "function")
```

What can I do to convert it to this:

```
>tt "test AS test", "this AS this", "function AS function"
```

I tried a few iterations of paste but couldn't quite get what I want.

Comment: Just as an aside, I'm automating some SQL string construction, hence the weird request.

Comment: Look at `paste`, `paste0`, `sprintf` and in the gsubfn package `fn`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`paste` is vectorized:

```
> tt <- c("test", "this", "function")
> paste(tt,"AS",tt)
[1] "test AS test"         "this AS this"         "function AS function"
```

Comment: ^^ Assumed paste wasn't vectorized because of this question, but this will be faster than my answer

Comment: Thanks, this is even better.  I was trying to get this to work earlier and was not following the vector application, thank you.

Comment: `sprintf("%s AS %s", tt, tt)` as suggested by  G. Grothendieck

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `sapply`

```
> sapply(tt, function(X) paste0(X, " AS ", X))
                  test                   this               function 
        "test AS test"         "this AS this" "function AS function"
```

Comment: If the names are annoying, `sapply` has the argument `USE.NAMES`